# How can I reduce the number of image files in my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, file-upload, filesystems

Hi  have recently changed to a new web host and noticed that my Wordpress website has a large number of files.

After investigating a little I have noticed that the media uploads is where there are a lot of files, this is the reason I’m asking the question

After a little bit of a read I’ve thought of 4 ways I can reduce this am just looking for some advice and help on this.

The methods are as follows:

Method 1: when an image is uploaded to only create image sizes that the uses, although I’m am unsure on what image sizes are used in my theme.

Method 2: only upload 1 image file and then the with a piece of code and image is dynamically created in the correct size based on what size is required

Method 3: a CDN if this would help?

Method 4: a plug-in ? If so any recommendations

I’m not looking at reducing the file size just the amount of files stored on the server it’s self, I already use a lossless file size reduction tool prior to uploading the images

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's in these numerous files ?

Comment: They are image files so png, jpg etc

Comment: I know, this does not answer my question. Why are there so many ?

Comment: So I think for every one image there is 16 different sizes made, there are like 25 images uploaded for every product  and there currently 1000 products

Comment: I would expect 4 sizes per image, not 16. https://enginescout.com.au/wordpress-image-sizes/